# T-SQL - Verify that all values are included in the result of a select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2016

Let say I have a function in which I pass a comma separated list of values. Then I have another function which returns a table. How can I verify that each of the values from the comma separated list is included in the result of the second function? If the comma separated list contains a value that is not in the result from the second function, the result must be FALSE.

**Valid scenario:**

input: A, B, C

result from second function: A, B, C, D

**Invalid scenario:**

input: A, B, C, D

result from second function: A, B, C

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that a comms separated list is *not* a good way to model multiple data items in T-SQL. T-SQL has types *designed* for holding multiple values (tables themselves, XML, JSON). Using a type not designed for holding multiple values (such as a string containing commas and other characters that then must be *parsed* or *shredded*) just adds complication to your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100)='1,3,4';

WITH splittedInput AS
(
    SELECT val.value('text()[1]','int') As theInt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@input,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS singleValue
    ) AS x
    CROSS APPLY x.singleValue.nodes('/x') As y(val)
)
SELECT *
FROM splittedInput AS si 
LEFT JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) AS t(x) ON t.x=si.theInt
WHERE t.x IS NULL;
```

Run this part separately

```
    SELECT val.value('text()[1]','int') As theInt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@input,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS singleValue
    ) AS x
    CROSS APPLY x.singleValue.nodes('/x') As y(val)
```

You see that this will return your comma separated input as derived table.

if you are using SQL Server 2016+ you can use `STRING_SPLIT()` which makes the whole thing much simpler.

The example is creating a simulated *result* using `VALUES` to return 1, 2, 3 and 4. the `LEFT JOIN` will return all the result values together with the joinable input values. If there is none, it will be `NULL`. Run it without the `WHERE` clause to see the difference.

Try to add a value to your input, which is not included in the output and try the script again.

### UPDATE

With a `SELECT` like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ResultIsValid
```

You'd get a single `0` or `1` marking the validity to return this - if needed.

### UPDATE 2: Using `STRING_SPLIT()`

With version 2016 MS introduced some new string methods, [one of them is `STRING_SPIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

I cannot test this at the moment (would need a SQL-Server 2016+) but this should work

```
SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@input,',') AS ss 
LEFT JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) AS t(x) ON t.x=ss.value
WHERE t.x IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks so far. Yes, we use SQL Server 2016+

Comment: @DraženJanjiček See my UPDATE 2